# Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am trying to launch chrome on my Android mobile which has chrome version: 76.0.3809.89

When I run my Java program, I get below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to automate Chrome version because it is too old for this version of Chromedriver.
Chrome version on the device: Chrome/76.0.3809.89
Visit 'https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md' to troubleshoot the problem.
Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75
  **(Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402** (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'abc', ip: '10.0.1.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to automate Chrome version because it is too old for this version of Chromedriver.
**Chrome version on the device: Chrome/76.0.3809.89**
Visit 'https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md' to troubleshoot the problem.
```

I have below questions:

1. From where it is picking `chromedriver=2.46.628402` as it mentions in the log ?
2. How to fix this error?

My code:

```
package browserTest;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class ChromeTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "My Android Mobile");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "521010f9ee4fb499");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
        cap.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
        cap.setCapability("noReset", true);

        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        //Open URL in Chrome browser
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm using Windows and AppiumServer with nodejs

you can download at https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
matching chrome driver version

and change chrome driver at

C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win

with this command **chromedriver.exe -version**

you can check version like this

C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appiu
m-chromedriver\chromedriver\win>**chromedriver.exe -version**

ChromeDriver 2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1)

C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appiu
m-chromedriver\chromedriver\win>**chromedriver.exe -version**

ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.12 (220b19a666554bdcac56dff9ffd44c300842c933-refs/branch-
heads/3809@{#83})

Answer (score 0):

You need the correct chromedriver which can handle Chrome 76 on your device.

You can try to set in manually with appium see [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/):

> npm install appium --chromedriver_version="76.0.3809.68"

Another option that should work would be to use the [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager).
It automatically downloads the correct driver and sets the capabilities accordingly.
Just add it to your project.

For example if you have a gradle project add following line to your build.gradle:

> compile group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager',
>   version: '3.6.2'
>   Then you need to set the chromedriver in your driver capabilities:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
cap.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getBinaryPath());
```